# Confusing notification about edits to Documentation

Tags: support, documentation, proposed-changes

A conversation about a proposed edit has appeared in my inbox. There's no link to the original (it's some sort of dispute about comment formatting), and I don't really understand what my role should be or why it's appearing in such a prominent place.

Comment: You mean by E-Mail? That sounds like a message sent by a disgruntled user, rather than Stack Overflow (although you don't seem to be publishing your E-Mail address in your profile, so it's weird). Stack Overflow doesn't send E-Mails  to you unless explicitly requested.

Comment: I mean my stack overflow inbox.

Comment: What kind of a conversation is it? Is it a series of comments?

Comment: Basically someone has rejected a change to a C article on "Pointers". The original editor has then come back with a defence of his change. It's a change in comment formatting. However there's no context, no link, and it's not obvious what I'm expected to about it.

Comment: A "dispute" has very high odds of disappearing without a trace.  Moderators cut it short, the only practical way to put a stop to it.  Best to avoid stretching the agony into torture, meta can only provide destruction.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Can you post a link to the discussion you were notified about please? I agree we need to tweak how these show up in the inbox and/or make them link to the specific item on the Discussion page that triggered the notification. Right now it's definitely too hard to tell what actually happened.